# iOS UIBarButtonItem icons: Facebook / Twitter / Email

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, icons, uibarbuttonitem

Has anyone created icons for a UIBarButtonItem for Facebook/Twitter/Email?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For email, you may find the professional-quality images on the site below useful. Yes, there's a small cost but they are pretty awesome.

http://www.glyphish.com

For Twitter/Facebook... just use Google and resize them as you require.

Comment: The issue is that the Twitter/Facebook icons are then coloured, which is usually fine, but in this context they stand out and don't look like UIBarButtonItems. The trick is to get the Facebook/Twitter icons to look like one of the default UIBarButtonItems.

Comment: Have you looked at the initWithImage: call that you can make to replace the default bar buttons? Just grab one of the images off the web, resize to 20 x 20px (see the UIBarButtonItem class reference if unsure) and it should work fine. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the existing [Where can one find free software icons / images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images) question.

Personally, I recommend [Iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/).